# How to make subString in Swift?

Tags: string, swift

Let say I have values like this

Apple(100)

Orange(300)

Pineapple(10)

Grape(50)

Banana(1000)

If I am going to remove (xx) from each string,what do I need to do in Swift?Any Help Please?
I can find only methods that can cut string with range.But,I am having problem with that.

What i want was

Apple

Orange

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
var string = "Apple(100)"                               //"Apple(100)" 
let newStr = string.componentsSeparatedByString("(")    //["Apple", "100)"]
newStr[0]                                               //"Apple"
```

And if you want to modify whole array then you can use this function:

```
func seprateString(arr: [String]) -> [String] {
    var newArr = [String]()
    for item in arr {
        let newStr = item.componentsSeparatedByString("(")
        newArr.append(newStr[0])
    }
    return newArr
}


let fruitArr = ["Apple(100)", "Orange(300)", "Pineapple(10)", "Grape(50)", "Banana(1000)"]
let newArrayForFruit = seprateString(fruitArr)
```

OutPut will be:

```
["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Grape", "Banana"]
```

Comment: Second line, comment should be `//["Apple", "100)"]`, missing `)`.

Comment: Any help with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204853/how-to-change-my-string-to-custom-array-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pure Swift 2 version ...

```
func stripBraces(s: String) -> String {
  guard let range = s.rangeOfString("(") else {
    return s
  }

  return s.substringToIndex(range.startIndex)
}

let strings = [ "Apple(100)", "Orange(300)", "NoBraces" ]
let strippedStrings = strings.map(stripBraces)
print(strippedStrings)
```

... if your string will be more complex, consider using `NSRegularExpression` for example.

Comment: Any help with that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204853/how-to-change-my-string-to-custom-array-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are in an array, you can map them with an one-liner

```
let fruitArray = ["Apple(100)", "Orange(300)", "Pineapple(10)", "Grape(50)", "Banana(1000)"]
let mappedArray = fruitArray.map { (string : String) in string.substringToIndex(find(string, "(")!)}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you should use `indexOf` on collection instead of `find` in Swift 2.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but there is no Swift2 tag ;-)

Comment: :-) Can't wait to see Swift10 tag :-)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 1:

```
return fruitArray.map {
    $0[$0.startIndex..<(find($0, "(") ?? $0.endIndex)]
}
```

In Swift 2:

```
fruitArray.map {
    $0[$0.startIndex..<($0.characters.indexOf("(") ?? $0.endIndex)]
}
```

Comment: Any Help with that? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31204853/how-to-change-my-string-value-into-array-by-removing

Comment: It’s not clear why you’ve asked the question again – is it that the answer you accepted doesn’t actually do what you want? In which case, accept a different one (click the check next to a different answer).

Comment: Oh I see, you want to extract the numbers. Hang on.