# how to change my String Value into Array by removing "()"

Tags: arrays, string, swift

Let say I have values like this

Apple(100)

Orange(300)

Pineapple(10)

Grape(50)

Banana(1000)

What I want to do is to create an array which was like that to each string

["Apple","100"]

["Orange","300"]

What i tried was like that,but it doesn't meet my answer well enough

```
var myNewFruits = "Apple(200)"
var newStr = myNewFruits.componentsSeparatedByString("(")
```

The Output was

```
["Apple","200)"]
```

What i really want was

```
["Apple","200"]
```

Is there any help with Swift?Thank you.Because I am creating search with that,so,i really need it.

Comment: Your question seems very similar to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31203437/how-to-make-substring-in-swift). I would add an explicit link to the previous question, explaining how they differ - otherwise it might happen this is considered as duplicate and closed.

Comment: No,the first one can only seperate into ["Apple","200)"].But what i want was without ")".Thank you sir.

Comment: @62Shark It's better if you make that explicit at the top of your question here

Comment: honestly: you should be able to adapt the code from the first question's answer to fulfill your needs. Is it possible that you are just to lazy to code yourself and you make us write your code? @62Shark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `NSCharacterSet` and get the first two elements from the returned array:

```
let myNewFruits = "Apple(200)"
let newStr = myNewFruits.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "()"))[0...1]   // ["Apple", "200"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
func stringToArr(str: String) -> [String] {

    var newArr = [String]()
    var fullNameArr = split(str) {$0 == "("}
    newArr.append(fullNameArr[0])
    var last: String? = fullNameArr.count > 1 ? fullNameArr[1] : nil
    newArr.append(last!.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(")", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil))

    return newArr
}

var string = "Apple(100)"          //"Apple(100)"
let newArr = stringToArr(string)   //["Apple", "100"]
```